# Remove a variable from Workspace by String name

Tags: matlab, variables

Let's say I got a variable `var1` in my Workspace and a struct containing the name of this variable as field e.g:

```
a = 
    Name: 'var1'
      a1: 1
```

I want to remove the variable `var1` from my workspace by using the field from the struct.

I know that I can clear `var1` by `clear var1` or `clear 'var1'`

As `clear a.Name` does not work, I played around with using the eval function, but I can't get it to work.

Any Idea is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [function form](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html) to call `clear` as command form "always passes inputs as literal text and cannot pass variable values".

```
>> var1 = 2;
>> a.Name = 'var1';
>> whos()
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  a         1x1               184  struct              
  var1      1x1                 8  double              

>> clear(a.Name);
>> whos()
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  a         1x1               184  struct
```